# mysql join to different tables depending on value

Tags: mysql, join

I have a rather complex mysql problem. I have a table like this:

[image: table relation]

So I want to join the second table depending on the value of sink_node_type to different other tables.
the result should be something like

project.name sink_type_a.name sink_type_b.name.

I have tried something like:

```
select p.name, sa.name, sb.name
from project p
join node n on p.id = n.project_id
join sink_type_a sa on n.sink_id = sa.id and n.sink_type = 'a'
join sink_type_b sb on n.sink_id = sb.id and n.sink_type = 'b';
```

But while it works for a join with only one of the sink_type tables, the result set is empty if I try both. Seems both "and" clauses are considered at the same time and therefore exclude each other?
Is there a way to do a join like this? (In reality I have 6 of the sink_type tables)

Thank you very much for every hint!

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`. When you join with the table `sink_type_b` using a `JOIN`, all rows of `nodes` that are not of type `b` will be removed from the result. Using `LEFT JOIN` allows you to return all rows on the left side of the join.
`sa.name` will be `NULL` when this is a sink of type b, and `sb.name` will be `NULL` for a sink of type a.

```
SELECT p.name, sa.name, sb.name
FROM project p
JOIN node n ON p.id = n.project_id
LEFT JOIN sink_type_a sa ON n.sink_id = sa.id AND n.sink_type = 'a'
LEFT JOIN sink_type_b sb ON n.sink_id = sb.id AND n.sink_type = 'b';
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone googles this one day: While it somehow works with the left join, the results are not optimal, sth like

```
Project.name sink_type_a.name sink_type_b.name
    1          something
    1                            someotherthing
    2          something 
    2                            someotherthing
```

To get everything for one project in one line, I finally ended up using subqueries:

```
Select tab_a.pname, tab_a.sink_a, tab_b.sink_b from
(select p.name as "pname", sa.name as "sink_a" from project p join nodes n on p.id = project_id and n.sink_type = 'a' left join sink_type_a sa on n.sink_id = sa.id) tab_a full join
(select p.name as "pname", sb.name as "sink_b" from project p join nodes n on p.id = project_id and n.sink_type = 'a' left join sink_type_b sb on n.sink_id = sb.id) tab_b on tab_a.pname = tab_b.pname;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).